# Converting JSON String to ZonedDateTime in RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I am having issues getting a RequestMapping PUT request to work properly (Note: for all classes I have simplified for brevity/clarity). For RequestMapping I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> flagDevice (@RequestBody List<MobileDeviceData> deviceInfoList) String inAuthIdentity) {
// code here
}
```

MobileDeviceData class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ReportedDeviceData", schema="schemaName")
public class MobileDeviceData {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="activityDetectedDate")
    private ZonedDateTime activityDetectedDate;

    ....
}
```

And JSON payload looks something like this:

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "activityDetectedDate": "2015-11-06T08:32:05.994-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]"
}]
```

or like this:

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "activityDetectedDate": 1446829632891
}]
```

For the first way I get this error:

```
{"timestamp":1446829369320,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.ZonedDateTime] from String value ('2015-11-06T08:32:05.994-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6989f9; line: 2, column: 39] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.inauth.inex.entity.MobileDeviceData[\"activityDetectedDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.ZonedDateTime] from String value ('2015-11-06T08:32:05.994-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6989f9; line: 2, column: 39] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.inauth.inex.entity.MobileDeviceData[\"activityDetectedDate\"])","path":"/mobile/device/"}
```

For the second way (current time in millis):

```
{"timestamp":1446829912863,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.ZonedDateTime] from Long integral number (1446829632891); no single-long-arg constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@550eb04; line: 2, column: 39] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.inauth.inex.entity.MobileDeviceData[\"activityDetectedDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.ZonedDateTime] from Long integral number (1446829632891); no single-long-arg constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@550eb04; line: 2, column: 39] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.inauth.inex.entity.MobileDeviceData[\"activityDetectedDate\"])","path":"/mobile/device/"}
```

So my question is this:

1. How can I get either of those ways to work? Or is there a third way that would be considered best practice that I'm unaware of?
2. What would be awesome is to get both ways to work and then the clients could have the option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson, by default, does not know how to deserialize the values `"2015-11-06T08:32:05.994-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]"` and `1446829632891` into `ZonedDateTime` objects.

The first option is to write a custom `JsonDeserializer` for `ZonedDateTime` that knows how to deserialize both those values.

The second option, and the one you should use because it's so simple, is to register a `Module` that has this behavior already. An existing `Module` exists, [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310), `jackson-datatype-jsr310`. As the documentation states, you can register it implicitly

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
```

or explicitly

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

This means that you will have to create and inject your own `ObjectMapper` into the corresponding `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. (Actually, it seems Spring Web 4.1.x already registers this well known `Module`, so you shouldn't need to do anything else, just add the library to the classpath.)

---

There's also [`jackson-datatype-jdk8`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8).

Comment: Just to clarify... The solution for me (I'm using Gradle) - I was able to get this to work by adding compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.6.3' to my build.gradle project dependencies path